# Transforming href links on pageload using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I need to transform all the links(href values) to specific format

for example - if a page has a link http://www.exampledomain.com i want to convert its href to http://url.com/xyz?http://www.example.com

Below is the jquery i am using for this task (Note that i am new to jquery)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {  
    $('a').each(function() {
        var value = $(this).attr('href');
        $(this).attr('href','http://url.com/xyz?'+value);
    });
});
```

But above script is converting all the links of the website and my navigational links are also getting changed. **How can we filter to change only the href's of links that contain 'http' and 'www'?**

I know some kind of regex can be used for this purpose. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should check if the link is external..

Answer (score 2):

I thinks you should extract all internal links.

You can check if value match your criteria (`http://www`):

```
   $( document ).ready(function() {  
     $('a').each(function() {
     var value = $(this).attr('href');
     if(value.indexOf("http:\\www") > -1 ){
         $(this).attr('href','http://url.com/xyz?'+value);
     }

   });
```

But it will be better to extract all the internal links:

```
var myHost = new RegExp(location.host);

$('a').each(function(){
   var value = $(this).attr('href');
   if(!(myHost.test(value))){
     $(this).attr('href','http://url.com/xyz?'+value);
   }
});
```

The last and better option is to take just the external links: ( if you don't have to do anything to the internal)

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {  
    $("a[href^='http']").each(function() {
     var value = $(this).attr('href');
     $(this).attr('href','http://url.com/xyz?'+value);
    }

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the link is external or internal then you can add the additional effort.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {  
 $('a').each(function() {
 var value = $(this).attr('href');
  if($(this[href^='http'])
  {
     $(this).attr('href','http://url.com/xyz?'+value);
   }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try for the following code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {   
    $('a').each(function() {
        var value = $(this).attr('href');
        if(value.match("http://www.*"))
        {
            $(this).attr('href','http://url.com/xyz?'+value);
        }
    });
});
```

You have to make sure that no navigation link contain

```
"http://www"
```

in them. Use relative links where you dont want to replace the href.

Or you could give a class to all anchor tags which you want to modify accordingly

Answer (score 1):

***[`Demo Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/8z5am/)***
<sub>*Check the anchor tag's href using element inspector*</sub>

```
$('a').each(function() {
   var a = new RegExp('/' + window.location.host + '/');
   if(!a.test(this.href)) {
       var value = $(this).attr('href');
      $(this).attr('href','http://url.com/xyz?'+value);
   }
});
```

using [`window.location.host`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp) and [`test`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp)

> Modified from [this article](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/open-external-links-in-new-window/) at CSS-Tricks.com

Answer (score 1):

One approach:

```
// selects all 'a' elements:
$('a')
// sets the 'href' attribute, using the anonymous function to iterate over each
// 'a' element:
.attr('href', function(i,oldhref){
    // i:  the index of the current element in the returned collection,
    // oldhref: the value of the 'href' before manipulation by the function.
    // if 'exampledomain.com' features in the hostname of the link we 
    // manipulate the 'href' as required, otherwise we simply set the 'href'
    // to its original value:
    return this.hostname.indexOf('exampledomain.com') > -1 ? 'www.url.com/xyz?' + oldhref : oldhref;
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LqpE5/).

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).
- jQuery:

  - [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).